# inherit code in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to inherit a constant var which are in another file/class. But I tried almost everything and I can't do it for some reason, can anyone tell me what is wrong or just are happening in my code please?

this is my main class that i called BasePage.

```
            class BasePage extends CI_Controller {

                const $TITLE = "My Own DB";

            }
```

and this is the other class/file which is trying to inherit to other class by giving the constant var TITLE into an array.

```
            <?php
            defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

            require 'BasePage.php';

            class Home extends BasePage {

                public function index()
                {
                    $data = array('title' => $TITLE);

                    $this->load->helper('url');
                    $this->load->view('page_login', $data);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constant should not have a $ at the beginning.

And you don't access it like `$TITLE`, or just `TITLE`, but with `self::TITLE`. In this case it would be most correct to use `parent::TITLE`, since it belongs to a parent class.

This should work:

```
        class BasePage extends CI_Controller {

            const TITLE = "My Own DB";

        }
```

---

```
        <?php
        defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

        require 'BasePage.php';

        class Home extends BasePage {

            public function index()
            {
                $data = array('title' => parent::TITLE);

                $this->load->helper('url');
                $this->load->view('page_login', $data);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Also, there is  `APPPATH . 'config.php';` file that is used for setting constants. Also should be considered what [constants](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/reserved_names.html#constants) names not to use.